# Write a Multi-Line String with Variable Values Included

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, c++17

I have program parameters which require me to have a single formatted string containing the values of variables input during the course of the program. Because of the amount of data involved, newlines for each new point of data would be ideal.

I'm using Visual Studio's C++ compiler, and have the following headers already:

```
//preprocessors
#include <iostream>
#include "MortCalc.h"
#include <string>
#include <istream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
```

I tried to concatenate the values and string fragments like this:

```
//write info to string
    string mortgageInfo =
        "       Principal Of Loan:      $" + mortData.principal + "\n"
        + "     Interest Rate:          " + mortData.interest + "%\n"
        + "     Monthly Payment:        $" + monthlyPayment + "\n"
        + "     Total Loan Paid:        $" + total + "\n"
        + "     Total Interest Paid:        $" + interestOverLife + "\n"
        + setprecision(0) + fixed + "\n"
        + "     Years:          " + mortData.term + "\n"
        + "     Start Date of Loan:     " + mortData.dayStart + "/"          
        + mortData.monStart + "/" + mortData.yearStart + "\n"
        + "     End Date of Loan:       " + mortData.dayEnd + "/" 
        + mortData.monEnd + "/" + mortData.yearEnd + "\n";
```

but I keep getting this error: "expression must have integral or unscoped enum type".

I'm basing this format on how a cout statement works, and replaced all '<<' with '+' to concatenate on, rather than the 'next statement' the double carrots mean.

Am I on the right track? Missing something obvious? Can this be done, at all?

Comment: You absolutely **CANNOT** add integers to a string... Use [`std::to_string()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)...

Comment: You should use string stream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the `setPrecision` and `fixed` modifiers when doing string concatenation.
You can do that using a `std::stringstream` however:

```
// In the header
#include <sstream>

// In your function
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "       Principal Of Loan:      $" << mortData.principal << '\n';
ss << "       Interest Rate:          " + mortData.interest + "%\n";
// more lines...
string mortgageInfo = ss.str();
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is *slightly deviated* from *what you think it does*...

The line of code is using the [`operator+()` derivative of the `std::string` class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)... And *unfortunately* it **does not allow integers or any other *non-string values* inside of it...**

**You, *however* have two options:**

1. Using [`std::to_string()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) from *C++11*...

**Example:** (*Not clean!*)

```
#include <string>
int main() {
    some_function_that_uses_only_strings("ABC" + std::to_string(number));
}
```

2. Or just use `std::stringstream`, and `std::cout`, itself is a `std::istream`, so its syntax is same and looks like a better way both in syntax and also from your question...

**Example:**

```
#include <sstream>
int main() {
    std::stringstream some_stream;
    some_stream << first_number << "ABC" << number << std::endl;
    some_function_that_uses_only_strings(some_str.str());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String Literals ("...") are of type const char*, not std::string, and their operator+ is not concatenation but rather adding to the pointed to memory address.

Either use "..."s to actually create std::string literals (but std::fixed etc still wont work) or create a

```
std::stringstream out;
```

And then use operator<< like you're used to from std::cout.
To get the string out of a stringstream, use the .str() member function.